# How do I determine if a string is numeric?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I thought this would be easier to find, but I'm quite surprised that it isn't.

How on Earth do I test if a string is a number (including decimals) outside a Model?

e.g.

```
is_number("1") # true
is_number("1.234") # true
is_number("-1.45") # true
is_number("1.23aw") #false
```

In PHP, there was `is_numeric`, but I can't seem to find an equivalent in Ruby (or Rails).

So far, I've read the following answers, and haven't gotten any closer:

- [Ruby on Rails - Validate a Cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173530/ruby-on-rails-validate-a-cost)
- [Ruby/Rails - How can you validate against decimal scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098990/ruby-rails-how-can-you-validate-against-decimal-scale)
- [invalid decimal becomes 0.0 in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039378/invalid-decimal-becomes-0-0-in-rails)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate number with rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924153/validate-number-with-rails-3)

Comment: @JustinWood the solution there doesn't apply to strings

Comment: Lets look at the root of the problem. How are you getting this string that may or may not be a `Numeric`?

Comment: @JustinWood it's an API parameter. The validation logic should work in any context

Comment: Would it be unacceptable to convert it to an int?

Comment: @JustinWood yes it would. It's a decimal.

Comment: Convert it to a float than?

Comment: why don't you use just regex?

Comment: @JustinWood convert it to float, and rescue the Exception? Sounds convoluted..

Comment: @bkdir I guess we could, but readability takes a hit.

Comment: What Exception? `value.to_f` should never throw an exception...

Comment: @JustinWood Unfortunately using `to_f` you cannot distinguish between non numeric strings and zeros: `'0'.to_f # => 0.0`, `'foo'.to_f # => 0.0`.

Comment: @JustinWood I like it. The only downside is that `"apple".to_f` is `0.0`, but in my case that's invalid too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if string is a number in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could borrow the idea from the [`NumericalityValidator`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb) Rails uses to validate numbers, it uses the [`Kernel.Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) method:

```
def numeric?(string)
  # `!!` converts parsed number to `true`
  !!Kernel.Float(string) 
rescue TypeError, ArgumentError
  false
end

numeric?('1')   # => true
numeric?('1.2') # => true
numeric?('.1')  # => true
numeric?('a')   # => false
```

It also handles signs, hex numbers, and numbers written in scientific notation:

```
numeric?('-10')   # => true
numeric?('0xFF')  # => true
numeric?('1.2e6') # => true
```

Comment: So I would have to define this method then, right? (i.e. it's not built-in)

Comment: Yes, there's no built-in or library function for the purpose.

Comment: Is seems like such a common use-case that it ought to be built in to the ruby library. I wonder if there is a reason why it is not built in?

Answer (score 4):

You could use Regular Expression.

```
!!("1" =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\z/) # true
!!("1.234" =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\z/) # true
!!("-1.45" =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\z/) # true
!!("1.23aw" =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\z/) # false
```

You can use it like this or make a method in a module or add this in the String class

```
class String
  def is_number?
    !!(self =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\z/)
  end
end
```

You can use this site to test your expression : [Rubular: a Ruby regular expression editor and tester](http://rubular.com/)

I can explain much more the expression if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This fails with values in bases larger than 10 such as `0xdeadbeef`

Comment: Why downvote ? The OP didn't indicate he want to test a specific base or other than 10. And it's possible to change the regular expression, so the answer remain valid.

Comment: @FredPerrin i got your back